# How to migrate files on Linux from HDD to SSD on a VDS

Tags: linux, swap, ssd

I upgraded my Dedicated Server and I was having problems finding my SSD.

I found out how to MOUNT my SSD. I now have my 100 GB HDD and now 20 GB HDD.

```
[root@server /]# mount /dev/xvdb1 /ssd
[root@server /]# df -h
Filesystem            Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/xvda2             99G  6.6G   87G   8% /
tmpfs                 938M     0  938M   0% /dev/shm
/dev/xvda1            194M   50M  134M  28% /boot
/dev/xvdb1             20G  7.0M   19G   1% /ssd
[root@server /]#
```

My goal is to transfer everything over to `/ssd` but I need to bring services over like httpd and mysqld along with my databases and things and make them run on the SSD.

How can I make this move?

Comment: Do you want to keep the root filesystem on the HDD and only move some files to the SSD, or do you want to transfer the whole system over to the SSD?

Answer (score 1):

In solving these kind of things you have essentially two options after moving the data:

- create symbolic links using `ln -s new_location old_location`
- update the configuration file for the service to point to the new location (how this is done depends on the service).

**most** important is that you stop the service before moving any files, otherwise corruption or data loss is likely to occur. You can often do this with `stop service_name` or `/etc/init.d/service_name stop`.

What I recommend to do after stopping the service is to use something like:

```
cd /srv
find httpd -depth -print0 | cpio -pdmv0 /ssd/srv
mv httpd httpd.org  
ln -s /ssd/httpd /srv/httpd
```

and restart the service ( keep `httpd.org` around, so you can quickly move it back if necessary until new location  works then delete).

Comment: so for instance ln -s /hdd/httpd/whatever /ssd/httpd/whatever.

Comment: So I would take note of all my directories, transfer them then link it. Is there any way I can currently see these "symbolic links"? Like to check what is linked to what?

Comment: You can check where the symbolic link points at with `ls -l /ssd` (or whatever the directory they are created in). And if you have created them corectly, `ls /hdd/httpd` should show you the files and subdirectories again.

Comment: Some applications don't like symlinks in certain contexts - e.g. opinting your document_root in apache to a symlink will result in lots of 404 errors if you've configure -FollowSymLinks. Further you may run into concurrency issues if the same file is accessed via different paths. NB I'm not saying this is not the way to fox the problem, just that there are hidden gremlins with symlinks.

Comment: @symcbean you are right, not all applications allow to do symlinks. For apache it depends on the level at which you have the symlink IIRC. Trying it first doesn't take that much time though.